# JQuery one function for several buttons

Tags: jquery, html

Im having quite a trouble finding words for this problem i have stumbled across.

Well, i have a link (normal a href) what i want that to do is on click i want a div to be shown which has the class of .more. Though i will have this in an ul so i need this function to work on several links all displaying the second div in an li with class .more.

This is the HTML markup, i'll hope you understand my question.

Thank you!

```
<li>
<div class="less">
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>12:00 - 13:00</p>
<a class="show_more" href="">Show more</a>
</div>
<div class="more" id="more_">
<p class="text">text</p>
<p class="place">Room / <a href="" class="address">An address</a></p>
<a class="show_less" href="">Show less</a>
</div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A href shouldn't be empty, so you should add `#` to the href, and then target the anchor, find the `.less` element, and the next `.more` element would be the one to show.
When clicking the `.show_less` button it would be the closest `.more` element you're going to hide :

```
$('.show_more').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.less').next('.more').show();
});

$('.show_less').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.more').hide();
});
```

Comment: For these kinds of jumps I recommend `closest` + `find` as that has the least amount of HTML structure hard coded into the JavaScript code. With `next`, it's too tightly coupled which is unnecessary IMO.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - If the markup is consistent that's not an issue, and I'm guessing `next()` uses `nextSibling` and is faster than `find()`

Comment: @adeneo The markup may be consistent (as in uniform), but if it's based on a template, it's very easy to perform changes to the entire structure, which can lead to the JS code becoming broken. I wouldn't worry about performance with `find`. It's a sub-tree query and it only runs once per click. However, not doing event delegation *does* have a  potential performance impact I think.

Comment: event delegation should be for dynamic elements, on anything else it's useless, and IMO the performance gains are a myth, unless you're attaching a huge number of event handlers. As for `next()`, it's more specific than `find()`, and in my book, specific is good, writing code that fixes other sloppy code just to be sure is not. Both answers work, that's the important part, and for this use case, the performance isn't an issue either way.

Comment: Now i got another problem, i decided to go with just one link. So i toggled the class show_more to get rid of it and then toggled show_less to add it though when i click the button again it doesn't perform the on click function for show_less, i checked the html and all looks right there.

Comment: @adeneo Some good points [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/10572150#105721500)

Answer (score 2):

```
$wrapper.on('click', 'a.show_more', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('li').find('.more').show();
});
```

where `$wrapper` is a jQuery object referencing the wrapper element of your thing, e.g. the UL element in this case.